# How to set the repository locale in alfresco?

Tags: alfresco

I need to set the repository locale within the alfresco repository so that all my email notifications are sent out in the right language as opposed to the default (english). I have searched but nothing has turned up so far.

Comment: Have you tried changing the locale of your server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little searching, I found that this was linked to the server's locale which can be overridden by setting the Java opts in the container startup script

and answered in [this post](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/installation-upgrades-configuration-integration/configuration/solved-daily-email-notification). Thanks Loftux